# Access variable within function

Tags: json, function, callback, response

Within a JSON Geocode GetResponse, the code provided by Microsoft uses a function to return results. However, I want to use results outside of the function, but I cannot access the data from within the function afterwards. Maybe the code can explain this more clearly:

```
    Dim geocodeRequest As New Uri(String.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q={0}&key={1}", query, key))
    Dim latlong_adress As BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Location = Nothing

    GetResponse(geocodeRequest, Function(x)
                                    MsgBox(x.ResourceSets(0).Resources.Length & " result(s) found.")
                                    latlong_adress = x.ResourceSets(0).Resources(0)
                                    'Correct results:
                                    MsgBox(latlong_adress.Confidence)
                                    MsgBox(latlong_adress.EntityType)
                                    MsgBox(latlong_adress.Point.Coordinates(0) & ", " & latlong_adress.Point.Coordinates(1))
                                    Return 0
                                End Function)
    'Empty: --> is nothing
    If latlong_adress IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(latlong_adress.Confidence)
        MsgBox(latlong_adress.EntityType)
        MsgBox(latlong_adress.Point.Coordinates(0) & ", " & latlong_adress.Point.Coordinates(1))
    End If
```

How can I access the data from the response after the response has been made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, although I am not quite sure about the correctness of the answer. My problems with understanding the issue were related to the asynchronous type of the GetResponse operation.

I added an event as follows:

```vb
Public Event NewGeocode(ByVal LocationData As BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Location, ByVal successful As Boolean)
Private Sub geocodeLoop(Optional LocationData As BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Location = Nothing, Optional successfull As Boolean = False) Handles Me.NewGeocode
    If LocationData Is Nothing Then
        geocodeAddress()
    Else
        If successfull = True Then
            'Correct results:
            MsgBox(LocationData.Confidence)
            MsgBox(LocationData.EntityType)
            MsgBox(LocationData.Point.Coordinates(0) & ", " & LocationData.Point.Coordinates(1))
            geocodeAddress()
        Else
            MsgBox("Unsuccessfull")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub geocodeAddress()
    Dim key As String = ...
    Dim query As String = "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA"

    Dim geocodeRequest As New Uri(String.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q={0}&key={1}", query, key))
    Dim latlong_adress As BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Location = Nothing
    GetResponse(geocodeRequest, Function(x)

                                    If Not x.ResourceSets(0).Resources.Length = 0 Then
                                        RaiseEvent NewGeocode(x.ResourceSets(0).Resources(0), True)
                                    Else
                                        RaiseEvent NewGeocode(Nothing, False)
                                    End If
                                    Return 0
                                End Function)
End Sub
Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    geocodeLoop()
End Sub
```